# ¿Por qué me sale NULL al final del array cuando ejecuto este código?

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
app.get("/api/v1/takingStats/loadInitialData",(req,res) => {
 var newTakingStats =[{
 country: "Spain",
 year: "2017",
 film: "TadeoJones2",
 distributor: "PPI",
 money: "17.917.439 ",
 rank: "1",
 spectator:"3.227.410"
}, {
country: "Spain",
year: "2017",
film: "PerfectosDesconocidos",
distributor: "UPI",
money: "14.373.417 ",
rank: "2",
spectator:"2.256.917"
},{
country: "Spain",
year: "2017",
film: "LaLlamada",
distributor: "DEAPLANETA",
money: "2.705.357",
rank: "12",
spectator:"483.238"
},{
country: "Spain",
year: "2017",
film: "LaLibreria",
distributor: "ACONTRA",
money: "2.366.547",
rank: "13",
spectator:"373.837"
}]; 

if(takingStats.length<=0){ // si está vacío al hacer DELETE, entonces devolvemos los ingresos iniciales
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<=newTakingStats.length;i++){
      takingStats.push(newTakingStats[i]);
   }//corregir para que no salga null al final
```

El caso es que me sale NULL al final del array cuando se me crean los takingStats , no sé a que se debe ese null.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Te sala un `NULL` dentro del array, fuera del array o dónde? ¿dónde sacas por pantalla el array?  ¿no habrá más código que se ejecute aparte de ese y que estaría produciendo el `NULL`?

Comment: No hay más codigo que ese . Cuando se ejecuta el código y hago un GET normal me devuelve todos los objetos del array y dentro del array como ultimo elemento un NULL

Comment: i<=newTakingStats.length es por tu ultima condicion tus elementos inician en 0 y terminan en lenght-1 solo en tu condicional elimina el igual y queda i<newTakingStats.length asi llegas hasta al ultimo elemento de tu array

Comment: Bien visto @MiguelZarate, es casi seguro que es eso.